# Why my conda environment inherits all base packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I am trying to create a "clean" Python virtual environment using conda:

```
conda create -n somename python=3.7 --no-default-packages
```

But somehow I have access to all the packages installed in base inside this environment. `pip list` returns all the Python packages, and I can `import` those packages in `Python`.
However, the actual environment's "site-packages" folder does not contain those extra Python modules as the base folder does.

So what should I do to create an independent/separate virtual environment? I am using Windows10.

---

**I had PYTHONPATH/HOME explicitly specified in path, after deleting now it works good.**

Comment: you should try `which pip` to make sure pip is referring to the right version.

Comment: I tried `pip --version` which shows my pip is 19.2.1, which is up to date I think.

Comment: If you are using anacomda, you will have many pip installed in different locations, sometimes the `pip` comand may refer to a wrong `pip` whose location is not in the virtual environment you actually in, thus the packages are not right. So `which pip` will let you konw the location of the pip. It has nothing to do with the version.

Comment: @ToughMindI tried `where pip` which I assume is the equivalent `which` in windows, it returns both the pip.ext in the environment and the pip.exe in base. Is this an indication of error and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds silly, but make sure that you are actually activating the new environment. Also make sure to check that `which python` and `which pip` refer to the new environment, I've had problems before where tmux makes conda activations silently fail.

Comment: This is a good thing to check: to clarify, in conda, CREATING an environment does NOT activate it.  You have to activate it explicitly.

Comment: I also doubt if the environment is activated, but there is (env_name) prefix in the command prompt, and `which` is not recognized

Comment: Is the (env_name) prefix is the same as the name of the new environment you created. You said which is not recognized, are you on windows? maybe you can try `where pip` and `where python` instead?

Comment: @sgillen.The env name is correct. I tried `where pip`, it returns both the pip.exe in the environment and the pip.exe in base. Is this an indication of error and how to fix?

Comment: well I think the problem is that windows sees the base pip and uses that instead of the environment pip. Why that is happening is going to be very hard for us to answer without more information regarding the version of conda, and the way you installed it and activated your environment.

Comment: I think reinstalling anaconda should fix this problem, and I will try that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would also check your PYTHONPATH variable

```html
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

just in case you inherit dist-packages (check your ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc)

Comment: `echo %PYTHONPATH%` returns _C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\Lib_